# Why is this is an equivalence relation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-curves

Fulton makes the following definitions:

[image]

After he defines an equivalence relation:

[image]

The definitions he made seems very obscure to me and if anyone could show why this relation is an equivalence relation this would help me a lot to understand the applications of these definitions.

I really need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $\equiv$ is an equivalence relation, you only need the very last sentence of the big block above, namely that $div(zz') = div(z) + div(z')$ and that $div(z^{-1}) = -div(z)$. The first gives you transitivity of $\equiv$, the second symmetry. (To precise, you also need reflexivity, but I presume this is either easy to come by, or implicitely assumed to be the case anyway.)